# Typescript useState hook on an object does not save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I am not able to save the object which my axios return to my useState hook.
Regular hook with strings and boolean works perfectly. This one does not.
The axios call return the correct data in correct format.

I got following useState hook:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>({} as IUser);
```

And I am fetching data from my api which I try to save to my hook.

```
  const getUser = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('me'); // this holds the correct data {id:1,...}
    setUser(data);
    console.log(user); // setting this return nothing
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a more generic approach -

```js
const identity = x => x

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = []) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(_ => { 
    Promise.reolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, deps)

  return { loading, result, error }
}
```

Using `useAsync` in a component looks like this -

```js
const MyComponent = ({ userId = 0 }) => {
  const { loading, error, result } =
    useAsync(UserApi.getById, [userId])

  if (loading)
    return <pre>loading...</pre>

  if (error)
    return <pre>error: {error.message}</pre>

  return <pre>result: {result}</pre>
}
```

If you have many components which need to query a user, you can specialize `useAsync` accordingly -

```js
const useUser = (id = 0) =>
  userAsync(UserApi.getById, [id])

const MyComponent = ({ userId = 0 }) => {
  const { loading, error, result:user } =
    useUser(userId)

  if (loading)
    return <pre>loading...</pre>

  if (error)
    return <pre>error: {error.message}</pre>

  return <pre>user: {user}</pre>
}
```

Here's a code snippet you can run to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } =
  React

const identity = x => x

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = []) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(_ => { 
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, deps)

  return { loading, result, error }
}

const _fetch = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(x => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, x)))

const UserApi = {
  getById: (id = 0) =>
    id > 500
      ? Promise.reject(Error(`unable to retrieve user: ${id}`))
      : _fetch(`https://httpbin.org/get?userId=${id}`).then(res => res.json())
}
  
const useUser = (userId = 0) =>
  useAsync(UserApi.getById, [userId])

const MyComponent = ({ userId = 0 }) => {
  const { loading, error, result:user } =
    useUser(userId)

  if (loading)
    return <pre>loading...</pre>
  if (error)
    return <pre style={{color:"tomato"}}>error: {error.message}</pre>
  return <pre>result: {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>
}

const MyApp = () =>
  <main>
    <MyComponent userId={123} />
    <MyComponent userId={999} />
  </main>

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body)
```

```css
pre {
  background: ghostwhite;
  padding: 1rem;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

**truly custom**

Of course that's just one way you can design `useAsync`. How you design your custom hooks can wildly change how they are used -

```js
const MyComponent = ({ userId = 0 }) =>
  useUser(userId, {
    loading: _ => <pre>loading...</pre>,
    error: e => <pre style={{color:"tomato"}}>error: {e.message}</pre>,
    result: user => <pre>result: {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>
  })
```

Such a custom hook could be implemented like this -

```js
const identity = x => x

const defaultVariants =
  { loading: identity, error: identity, result: identity }

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = [], vars = defaultVariants) => {
  const [{ tag, data }, update] =
    useState({ tag: "loading", data: null })

  const setResult = data =>
    update({ tag: "result", data })

  const setError = data =>
    update({ tag: "error", data })

  useEffect(_ => {
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
  }, deps)

  return vars[tag](data)
}
```

And `useUser` is updated to pass along `cata`

```js
const useUser = (userId = 0, vars) =>
  useAsync(UserApi.getById, [userId], vars)
```

Verify the results by running the snippet below -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } =
  React

const identity = x => x

const defaultVariants =
  { loading: identity, error: identity, result: identity }

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = [], vars = defaultVariants) => {
  const [{ tag, data }, update] =
    useState({ tag: "loading", data: null })
    
  const setResult = data =>
    update({ tag: "result", data })

  const setError = data =>
    update({ tag: "error", data })

  useEffect(_ => {
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
  }, deps)

  return vars[tag](data)
}

const _fetch = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(x => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, x)))

const UserApi = {
  getById: (id = 0) =>
    id > 500
      ? Promise.reject(Error(`unable to retrieve user: ${id}`))
      : _fetch(`https://httpbin.org/get?userId=${id}`).then(res => res.json())
}
  
const useUser = (userId = 0, vars) =>
  useAsync(UserApi.getById, [userId], vars)

const MyComponent = ({ userId = 0 }) =>
  useUser(userId, {
    loading: _ => <pre>loading...</pre>,
    error: e => <pre style={{color:"tomato"}}>error: {e.message}</pre>,
    result: user => <pre>result: {JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>
  })

const MyApp = () =>
  <main>
    <MyComponent userId={123} />
    <MyComponent userId={999} />
  </main>

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body)
```

```css
pre {
  background: ghostwhite;
  padding: 1rem;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** State updates in `react` are asynchronous.

---

`setUser` is not directly updating `user` when it's called. `react` will update `user` but it will not tell you when exactly this is going to happen. The updated value will most likely be available in the next render.

If you want to sort of `await` a state update it's most of the time enough to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
useEffect(() => console.log(user), [user])
```

I also wrote a [blog post](https://dev.to/ysfaran/usestatewithpromise-a-custom-hook-to-await-state-updates-of-usestate-284o) about this topic which is kind of a deep-dive into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine but you are logging the data at wrong place.
On `getUSer` method both `await` and `setUser` are async api call but console is synchronous, that's why it console the `user` before it gets updated. 
Initially the `user` is {} that's why it gives nothing.